# Hilbert scheme of virtually zero-dimensional derived subschemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $S$ is a smooth projective surface then there is a scheme $\mathrm{Hilb}(S)$ of zero-dimensional subschemes. Is there a similar scheme parametrizing derived subschemes of virtual dimension 0?

Comment: What do you call a derived subscheme?